# How can I put a condition on a feature that disables it (instead of hiding it)?

Tags: wix

How can I have a Feature depend on a system dependency (e.g. powershell), but still indicate to users that this feature is available in the installer.

Currently features are listed as follows (screenshot):
[Feature List](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zllj3qbkd40je92/wix-feature-list.png?dl=0)

My current idea is to put a condition on the feature:

```xml
<Property Id="POWERSHELL_3_INSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="Powershell3Installed"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3"
                  Type="raw"
                  Name="Install" />
</Property>

<Feature Id="TestFeature" 
       Title="Test Feature" 
       Description="Test Feature Description. Note: This feature requires Powershell 3 or higher." 
       Level="1" 
       Absent="allow" 
       InstallDefault="local" 
       AllowAdvertise="no">
    <Condition Level="0">
      <![CDATA[(POWERSHELL_3_INSTALLED <> "#1") AND NOT REMOVE]]>
    </Condition>
</Feature>
```

This does hide `TestFeature` for users without powershell installed, preventing them to install it, but this way users are not aware that this extra feature would be available if they would install powershell.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: This depends on your UI - how are you displaying what features are available in your UI?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @Justin. A link to the screenshot has been added in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SelectionTree control in Windows Installer does not support showing disabled features. You would have to reimplement that -- for example, using checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Answer accepted, as I was indeed looking for a way without having to implement the functionality myself.